# Google App Engine Standard with java8 when it will be no longer beta version?

Tags: google-app-engine, java-8

I have a question with GAE standard mode with java. I checked the google site https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8 It still mentions that the GAE standard with java8 is still Beta version. Do you know when it will be GA version?

Sophea

Comment: Hi guys, I just got a really good news from Google. Java 8 on App Engine with standard environment is now generally available. check out more detail: https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/09/Java-8-on-App-Engine-Standard-environment-is-now-generally-available.html